# View can't access Model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations

I have a Controller that return a view with a model such as :

```
    public ActionResult AddSetStory()
    {
        StoryModel sm = new StoryModel();

        return View(sm);
    }
```

with model as :

```
namespace AStoryToTell.Views.Stories.StoriesModel
{
    public class StoryModel
    {
        public int IDStory { get; set; }
        public int IDUser { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string StoryDescription { get; set; }
        public string StoryText { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
        public string Base64File { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string tagsString { get; set; }

    }
}
```

but i cannot access it through my view

[image]

Even though I have the @model annotation as first line in my view :

```
@model AStoryToTell.Views.Stories.StoriesModel.StoryModel
```

What am I missing here ? Shouldn't Model be strongly typed as class StoryModel ??
What i don't understand is why it is not recognize by VS 2013 ?

Although if i do this :

```
<script>
    var someVariable = '@Model.tagsString';
    console.log(someVariable);
</script>
```

It will log what i've put in my model as attribute tagsString ..

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you're placing your ViewModels deeper in the hierarchy, than your View. Can you maybe try to put your ViewModels in a folder called "ViewModels" in the top of your folder hierarchy, to see if that works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've probably solved the problem but the exact same thing happened to me and I restarted visual studio (2013 Professional) and the issue got resolved.

Thought I'd post this for people who might stumble in here in the future.

Comment: Infuriating! Thank you, the exact same thing happened to me and was solved with a restart.

Comment: It's amazing how many issues are solved by that... I've been looking at this for the past 30 minutes. Thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, I restart the VS but didn't get well. The problem is placing the model classes deeper in the folders, from models/register/Class.cs -
models/Class.cs and issue resolved.